# Поиск товара без базы данных

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

Есть статичная страница "Список желаемых товаров"
На этой странице есть 4 таба по 8 товаров к каждом табе.
[image: Список желаемого]
Суть в том, что есть поле для поиска, при вводе 3 и более букв необходимо чтобы товары в списке фильтровались и отсеивались те, что не совпадают с запросом в строке поиска по товарам. Так же нужно учитывать то, что при удалении товара из списка желаемого - он не отображался в поиске (список удаленных товаров записывался в массив и не выводился при поиске на странице, (как я думаю)).
Одна единственная страница на html + css + bootstrap.
Второй день не могу найти в интернете что-то подобное, пытался вставить скрипт который фильтрует таблицы, но он не сработал. Сделать это нужно без базы данных т.е. поиск по дивам в которых находиться h4 заголовок с названием товара.
Может знаете что лучше всего подойдет, какой скрипт или готовое решение, потому что я абсолютно не знаю что делать. Вся проблема в том что нет базы данных, а по условию - базы не должно быть(
Буду очень благодарен Вашему совету или помощи

Comment: Мне видится 2 пути решения вашей проблемы, 1 - написать скрипт самостоятельно(возможно попутно задавая конкретные вопросы по **вами написанному коду**). 2 - Обратится на фриланс и заказать нужный вам скрипт там.

Comment: @Nick ваши наработки, в виде кода, здесь приветствуются и, возможно, сильно ускорят появление ответа.

Comment: @UModeL буду иметь ввиду, спасибо ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот кусочек из моего проекта, работает по input. Думаю принцип реализации ясен

```
$("#search").on("input", function () {

    var search=$(this).val();
    if(!search){  $("#goods").show(); return; }
    $("#goods").hide();

    $("#goods").each(function() {
        if( $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase())>=0 ){
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: спасибо большое, очень выручил скрипт

Comment: а можно ли как-то очистить фильтр поиска нажав на кнопку clear list ? 
(рядом с полем поиска)

Comment: @ANYWAYCODE  можно поставить input type="search" и будет появляться крестик для очистки

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете реализовать данную задача создав массив с объектами товаров и организовать выборку по имени товара из этого массива.

У меня так реализован TODO лист (только с базой данных). Из бд при загрузке все задачи импортируются в объект и больше с БД я не работаю. Организую поиск по объекту.